# Whitespace macro

Tags: macros, spacing

I would like to have a macro which produces N white spaces if called like this

```
\mulspc{3} % Produces exactly 3 spaces

\newcommand{\mulspc}[1]{
    \newcounter{ctra}
    \setcounter{ctra}{0}
    \whiledo {\value{ctra} < #1}%
    {
      \hspace*{2mm}
      \stepcounter{ctra}
    }
}
```

But I have problems that this macro does not produce 0mm spacing in a table cell (just at the beginning of the cell!) if I call zero times `\multspc{0}`.
There is always some indent, but where does this come from?

I need this macro to indent some algorithm in the table cell, its nasty but manualy formating gives me the best result in a longtable, because its multiple pages long...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need for using a loop:

```
\newlength\Unit
\setlength\Unit{2mm}
\newcommand\mulspc[1]{\hspace*{#1\Unit}}                           


foo\mulspc{4}bar
```

Comment: ...now that's clean! Nice!

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the current macro is that it unwanted whitespace is added from due to indentation. Add some `%` add the line ends to get rid of these. However, the current definition also produces a warning after you use `\mulspc` more than once. That is because the counter definition `\newcounter{ctra}` is contained within the `\newcommand{\mulspc}`. Rather define the counter **outside** the macro definition. Another drawback is that the space offered by `\mulspc{0}` should be non-existent, which it is not, even if you add `%` to remove the unwanted spaces. For example, the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcounter{ctra}%
\newcommand{\mulspc}[1]{
    \setcounter{ctra}{0}%
    \whiledo {\value{ctra} < #1}%
    {\hspace*{2mm}\stepcounter{ctra}}%
}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\mulspc{0}}% Zero spaces

\fbox{}% Empty \fbox

\fbox{\mulspc{1}} % One space

\fbox{\mulspc{3}} % Produces exactly 3 spaces

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: Unwanted spacing in \mulspc]

To get rid of this spacing, you could use a condition on the parameter passed to `\mulspc`:

```
\newcommand{\mulspc}[1]{
  \ifthenelse{#1>0}{%
    \setcounter{ctra}{0}%
    \whiledo {\value{ctra} < #1}%
    {\hspace*{2mm}\stepcounter{ctra}}%
  }{\unskip}%
}
```

providing `\unskip` if there is a parameter passed with value less than `1`. This produces:

[image: Unwanted spaces gone from \mulspc]

---

Another alternative would be to use the easy interface of the [`multido` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multido), and define (say)

```
\usepackage{multido}% A loop facility for Generic TeX
...
\newcommand{\Mulspc}[1]{%
  \multido{\iA=0+1}{#1}{\hspace*{2mm}}%
}
```

that you can use in a similar way, and is a little cleaner code-wise.

Comment: That is not because of indentation.  Even if you start every line from the first column, a space is still added because of the newline.

Answer (score 1):

eTeX is always available nowadays, thus you can simply use

```
\newcommand\mulspc[1]{\hspace*{#1\dimexpr2mm}}
```